# What to use instead of global when I can't pass the variable into the function

Tags: python, global-variables

I am using the websockets Python package and the code being executed is within the `on_message` function, so I'm unable to pass my variable into the function, but I don't want to use `global`.

I set some variables before defining my functions:

```
Symbol = "BTCUSDT"
interval = "1m"

EMA_period = 28

MACD_fast_period = 12
MACD_slow_period = 26
MACD_signal_period = 9

historic_highs = []
historic_lows = []
historic_closes = []
MACD_CrossBool = [None, None]
in_position = False
```

Within my `on_message` function, I need to use `in_position` in some if statements:

```
def on_message(ws, message):
    global in_position
    # ------------------------- Unpack JSON message data ------------------------- #
    json_message = json.loads(message)
    candle = json_message['k'] # Accesses candle data

......[Other code here]......

        if MACD_CrossOver == True and trend == 1:
            if not in_position:
                print("Buy order")
                in_position = True

        if MACD_CrossUnder == True and trend == -1:
            if not in_position:
                print("Sell order")
                in_position = True

......[Other code here]......

    if in_position:
        if buy_order['status'] and close <= long_stop_price:
            sell_order = margin_order(buy_order['symbol'], SIDE_SELL, buy_order['quantity'], close, ORDER_TYPE_LIMIT)
            print("Long stop-loss triggered")

        if sell_order['status'] and close >= short_stop_price:
            buy_order = margin_order(sell_order['symbol'], SIDE_BUY, sell_order['quantity'], close, ORDER_TYPE_LIMIT)
            print("Short stop-loss triggered")
```

So is there a different way I can make this work without having to use `global in_position` at the start of function? Also, I can't set the variable on each message as that wouldn't work how I need it to.

Comment: What do you mean, you can't pass the variable to the function? Why not?

Comment: if you want to change what a global name refers to inside a function you need to use `global`, also you can try using `class`es or putting the variable inside a dictionary like this for example: `data = {'in_position': False}` and when you want to change it do `data['in_position'] = True` and stuff like that but that will make it slower so just use `global`

Comment: @mapf the `on_message` fucntion from the websockets package is defined in the websockets package, so you can't pass an argument into that it's not expecting

Comment: I see. But then why can you add the `global in_position` statement?

Comment: If a function you can't change uses a global variable as part of its interface, then you have to use a global variable. If you simply need to define a *callback* function that expects to receive two arguments, then you can define a class where `in_position` becomes an instance attribute of an instance whose bound method becomes the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a `dict` like a `database`

```
database = {
    "symbol": "BTCUSDT",
    "interval": "1m",
    "EMA_period": 28,
    "MACD_fast_period": 12,
    "MACD_slow_period": 26,
    "MACD_signal_period": 9,
    "historic_highs": [],
    "historic_lows": [],
    "historic_closes": [],
    "MACD_CrossBool": [None, None],
    "in_position": False
}
```

I hope I could help.

Comment: mutable objects don't need to be stored in a dict since usually you don't change the reference but the object itself, also this will be slightly slower than using `global` AFAIK but OP wanted to know what to use instead so...